# AWS Batch Boto3 Change Job_ID

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3, aws-batch

I am running a boto3 batch client job and using the `submit_job` function like so:

```
submit_job_response = batch.submit_job(
        jobName=job_name,
        jobQueue=job_queue,
        jobDefinition=job_definition,
        parameters=parameters,
        containerOverrides={"command": command_list, "environment": environment},
    )
```

Now, this is running correctly and jobs are running successfully. My question is (I don't see anything in the documentation for this), can I update the job_id AWS Batch creates to be human readable? Right now the job_id in the UI is a uuid, but I would like to add a string value to this so it can be more easily read in the UI.

Comment: You might have to create a separate table of human-readable ids to real id and use that. Another option is some kind of transformation on the real id (like take just the last 6 letters), but that might cause conflicts. If it's only for display purposes, that might be enough.

Comment: Yeah, this could all probably be added into a DynamoDB table. I wasn't sure if there was something built into Batch, natively.

Comment: Why not use job name

Comment: Looking back at the boto3 docs, I was confusing that with the name of the job_definition! `jobName` should do it.